# Closing android system dialog box automatically

Tags: android, dialog

Is there a way to close the android system dialog box automatically from the app code?? Or else to click a particular portion of a system dialog box when it appears?? I am trying to write a calling app and in that when someone tries to call and if the airplane mode is "on" a system dialog will appear asking to turn off the airplane mode. I want to know whether it is possible to click "ok" in this dialog box automatically...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You want the Dialog to disappear automatically?

Comment: Use a Toast instead ? or make a Custom Toast

Comment: @joao2fast4u I want to auto click an option in the dialog and thus closing it automatically. The dialog is not custom but a native android system dialog.

Comment: @Metalhead1247 I am not asking about toast. I want to click on one option in onscreen dialog like by specifying x and y co ordinates wwhen it pops up. But i dont know how to do it.

Comment: You are shiowing an AlertDialog, right? It only has one button?

Comment: If you just have on Button on your Dialog, you just do what you want to do when you click the Button, but instead put that code inside an OnDismissClickListener. Then you just have to use a Handler to autodismiss your Dialog.

Comment: @joao2fast4u What i am trying to ask is to autoclick on an option when a SYSTEM DIALOG box appears. Does not matter whether it has one button or more. I want to know is there any way to autoclick on any one option in the dialog (for eg. by knowing the x and y co ordinates of the option in the dialog, it will be autoclicked when it appears). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

onWindowFocusChanged method is called when focus is changed. So, we can use that method to disappear system dialog.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if(!hasFocus) {
        // Close every kind of system dialog
        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
}
```